# When the player hits the food make it disapear

Tags: java, processing

I am new to programing, so bare with me lol. Our teacher has given us a game in which we need to add some elements to it. It's a game where we have a player, some enemies and some food made out of rectangles. If the player hits the food i want the food to spawn somewhere else in the window. Heres is the code where im trying to make it happen:

```
 private void updateFood(){
     for(int i = 0; i < food.length; ++i)
    {
      //Should we follow or move randomly?
      //2 out of 3 we will follow..
      if(rnd.nextInt(3) < 2)
      {
        //We follow
        int dx = player.getX() - food[i].getX();
        int dy = player.getY() - food[i].getY();
        if(abs(dx) > abs(dy))
        {
          if(dx > 0)
          {
            //Player is to the right - opiste
            food[i].moveLeft();
          }
          else
          {
            //Player is to the left - opiste
            food[i].moveRight();
          }
        }
        else if(dy > 0)
        {
          //Player is down; - opiste
          food[i].moveUp();
        }
        else
        {//Player is up; - opiste
          food[i].moveDown();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        //We move randomly
        int move = rnd.nextInt(4);
        if(move == 0)
        {
          //Move right
          food[i].moveRight();
        }
        else if(move == 1)
        {
          //Move left
          food[i].moveLeft();
        }
        else if(move == 2)
        {
          //Move up
          food[i].moveUp();
        }
        else if(move == 3)
        {
          //Move down
          food[i].moveDown();
        }
      }
      if(food[i].getX() == player.getX() && food[i].getY() == player.getY()){
        food[i].getX() = random(0,width);
food[i].getY() = random(0,height);


      }
    }
  
    
  }
```

the last 10 lines (or so) is where im having the problem.

```
    if(food[i].getX() == player.getX() && food[i].getY() == player.getY()){
        food[i].getX() = random(0,width);

food[i].getY() = random(0,height);
```

Comment: Is the problem that your food doesn't register the collision, or that it's not teleporting after the collision (in doubt, you can add a `println("collision registered, food should teleport");` next to the `food[i].getY() = random(0,height);` line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With limited info on what methods your `food[index]` objects have, I'm going to guess `.getX()` is read-only, meaning you can't set a value to it. Either find a `.setX(number)` method, or use the existing `.moveLeft/Right/Up/Down(number)` with a bit of maths.